# EssentialAction: How to Get the Body of a Request without Parsing It

Tags: scala, playframework

Given the following `EssentialAction`...

```
object MyController extends Controller {

  ...

  def HasToken(action: Token => EssentialAction) = EssentialAction { request =>

    ...

    // this doesn't compile
    val body = request.body match {
      case json: JsValue => json.toString
      case _ => ""
    }

    // calculate hash with body content here
    ...
  }

  // here is an authenticated action
  def getUser(userId: Strign) = HasToken { token =>
    Action(parse.json) { request =>
      request.body.validate[User] match {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... how do I get the body of the request without parsing it?

I don't want and I don't need to parse the request body in `HasToken` since the body is going to be parsed in action `getUser`. I just need the raw content of the body to calculate a hash.

The code in `HasToken` doesn't compile because `request` is of type `RequestHeader` whereas I need a `Request`, which defines `body`.

Comment: The duty of HasToken is unclear. Where's the hasToken logic ? I only see that you are trying to access the body to calculate the payload hash. It's also unclear what you want. You want it to compile ? If so I must ask why your HasToken signature is Token => EssentialAction and not Token => Request.. If you want HasToken to not parse the body, then why not send the tokens in the RequestHeader if thats what you want ?

Comment: `HasToken` verifies the request header has a valid JSON Web Token... and the hash is used to verify the request hasn't been tampered. Anyway, these details are useless for my question. I'm just asking how to get the raw content of the request (I need it to calculate the hash, which must correspond to the one contained in the token).

Comment: "Anyway, these details are useless for my question." => I do not think so, if you accept my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work for you ?

```
object MyController extends Controller {

  // Your HasToken Action
  def Authenticate(action: Token => EssentialAction) = EssentialAction { requestHeader =>
    // ... execute logic to verify authenticity using requestHeader
  }

  // Your action to validate tampering of request body and validity of JSON
  def Validate[A](action: Token => Request[A]) = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    val body = request.body
    body match {
      case json: JsValue => json.toString
      case _ => ""
    }
    // calculate hash with body content here

    body.validate[User] match {
      // ...
    }
  }

  def getUser(userId: Strign) = Authenticate { token =>
    Validate { user =>
      //.... Continue
    }
  }
}
```

- Authentication only uses RequestHeader
- Validation uses Request body. (Bonus: Body is only parsed once)

EDIT:

**Question #1:** I don't want to validate the body in Validate... since I need a generic validation mechanism that could be used everywhere regardless of the content type (e.g. user, message, etc.).

How about adding another type param (so that it is made generic):

```
def Validate[A, B](action: Token => Request[A])(implicit reads: Reads[B]) = Action(parse.json) { request =>
   // ...
}
```

**Question #2:** Furthermore, if the token validation fails, the body don't have to be processed (that's important in case of file upload, which has to be performed if and only if the validation succeeded). That's way, in my opinion, the best option would be to read the raw content of the body in Validate.

This can be easily achieved:

```
def Validate[A, B](action: Token => Request[A])(implicit reads: Reads[B]) = Action(parse.json) { request =>
   val body = request.body
    body match {
      case json: JsValue => json.toString
      case _ => ""
    }
    // calculate hash with body content here and figure out if the body is tampered
    if (bodyIsNotTampered) {
      body.validate[B] match {
        // ...
      }
    } else {
      // log and return Future.successful(BadRequest)
    }
  }
```

**EDIT 3: Full solution:**

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, JsValue, Format}

object CompilationUtils {
  class Token
  case class User(name: String)
  implicit val UserFormat = Json.format[User]

  def authenticate = new Token // authentication logic

  def isTampered(body: JsValue) = {
    val bodyAsStr: String = Json.stringify(body)
    // calculate hash with body content here
    false
  }

}

object MyController extends Controller {
  import CompilationUtils._

  // Your HasToken Action
  def Authenticate(action: Token => EssentialAction) = EssentialAction { requestHeader =>
    action(authenticate)(requestHeader) // your execute logic to verify authenticity using requestHeader
  }

  // Your action to validate tampering of request body and validity of JSON
  def Validate[A, B](request: Request[A])(implicit formatA: Format[A], formatB: Format[B]): Either[Result, B] = {
    val body = request.body
    val bodyAsJsValue = Json.toJson(body)
    if (!isTampered(bodyAsJsValue)) {
      bodyAsJsValue.validate[B].fold(
        valid   = res => Right(res),
        invalid = err => Left(BadRequest(err.toString))
      )
    } else {
      Left(BadRequest) // Request Tampered
    }
  }

  def getUser(userId: String) = Authenticate { token =>
    Action(parse.json) { request =>
      Validate(request).fold(
        badReq => badReq,
        user   =>
          // continue...
          Ok("")
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to validate the body in `Validate`... since I need a generic validation mechanism that could be used everywhere regardless of the content type (e.g. user, message, etc.). Furthermore, if the token validation fails, the body don't have to be processed (that's important in case of file upload, which has to be performed if and only if the validation succeeded). That's way, in my opinion, the best option would be to read the raw content of the body in `Validate`.

Comment: @j3d: I addressed your comments. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: ... the problem is that the parser might be different depending on the request. For example it is `parse.Json` in case the body contains JSON, but in case of multipart/form-data (i.e. file upload) the parser would be `fsBodyParser`, a custom parser that stores incoming data directly into MongoDB.

Comment: @j3d: What is the problem is passing the BodyParser as well to the Validate Action ?

Comment: If the content is JSON, I need it in `Authenticate` because the authentication  process consists of concatenating token + request.method + request.path + body and generating a signature that must match to the one in the authentication request header. A possible body parser should be executed only after `Authenticate` and `Authorize` (`Authorize` is just another `EssentialAction` that verifies whether the user authenticated with the current Json Web Token [JWT] has permission to invoke the current endpoint).

Comment: OK, I'm reorganizing the code according to your response... but what  should `Validate` return? `action(token)` does not compile: `type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.EssentialAction
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Request[?]
[error]     EssentialAction { requestHeader =>
`

Comment: Venkat, thank you very much for your GREAT support ;-)